# Converting client-server applicatoin from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, converters

I have a client-server application that works kinda like a messenger, the application is built using C++ .. Now I'm building an application using C# that will require the same feature, so I was wondering if there is a way to convert the code from C++ to C# ..

The new application will be communicating with the server application over internet, VPN or IPSec .. Still under design phase.

Comment: What does the current application use for communication? Are you re-writing both sides? If so, why port at all?

Comment: The only way to convert code from C++ to C# is write C# code based on C++ code. If you have specific net structures (I guess you have), you can write some handy script to convert them to C#.

Comment: ANYWAY. @sikas: With some research effort and refactoring, you could probably reuse a fair bit of your existsing C++ code. If you encapsulate the required logic behind a clean, CLI-compatible API, you could use C++/CLI or P/Invoke to invoke it from C# code directly. Alternately, you could run it as a service somehow.

Comment: OK, I cleaned up the flamewar that was going on here because it wasn't constructive in the least. If you wish to continue that discussion, please take it to chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few converters I've found while searching with [Google](http://www.google.com/about/) which I hope you find helpful:

[C++ to C# Translator | Free Development software downloads at SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cxx2cs/)

[C++ to C# Converter](http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_CSharp_Converter_Details.html)

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

C++ and C# are completely different languages. So it is not possible to have any kind of automated conversion between the two.

You need to rewrite it from scratch by hand.

Answer (score 0):

For basic conversion you can use [Tangible C++ to C# Converter Code Converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CPlusPlus_to_CSharp_Converter_Details.html). After it you should correct generated C# code by hand.